# What is the correct way to name MyComponent and <MyComponent />?

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to explain to a friend of mine some core things about react and I came to the point where I was confusing him by not saying the appropriate name of `MyComponent` and `<MyComponent />` while explaining the difference.

e.g.

Having this component

```
function MyComponent(){
    return (<div />)
}
```

This two variables are different things

```
const Foo = MyComponent 
const Bar = <MyComponent />
```

`Foo` can be used to render and I call it a "reference to MyComponent" and `Bar` is already a "object"(`React.createElement`) to be rendered and I sometimes I call it a "React Element".

But calling it "reference of MyComponent" and a "React Element" doesn't feels right. I'm pretty sure this isn't the correct way to call it.

What is the correct way to name `MyComponent` and `<MyComponent />`?

Comment: That's pretty much right. `MyComponent` (and `Foo`) is a "component" and `<MyComponent />` (and `Bar`) is a "(React) element".

Comment: @FelixKling If I have a variable e.g. `const Hey = MyComponent`, isn't too vague calling `Hey` a "component"? Because it feels like everything is a component

Comment: I think the confusion might come from mixing up variable (names) and values. In your example, both `Hey` and `MyComponents` are just variables that have reference the same value (a function). It's that value that is actually the component. Which variables it the value is assigned to is basically irrelevant. But it's difficult to talk about it without giving it some kind of name... Similarly , `<MyComponent />` results in an object value when evaluated, and it's that object value that is the element.